# I have an addEvent function but the correct state is not being passed to it

Tags: reactjs

My app.js essentially creates a widget layout. It contains an add function which is intended to take the selectedWidgetId from the state and find it within an array of options. I have a handleWidgetSelection function which updates the selectedWidgetId state based on a selection in an external component. For example if the user picks "List" selectedWidgetId will be updated to "List". What I am noticing is the state is being updated in the handleWidgetSelection but when I use it in the add function and console log it it shows as the original state null and it is unable to find it in the widgetOptions array. Any help would be great.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state={
        selectedWidgetId: null,
        widgetOptions:[{name:"Data Table", comp:<DataTable/>},{name:"List", comp:<CheckboxList/>}],

        widgets:[ //array for layout 
          {id:1, content: <DataTable/>},
          {id:2, content: <CheckboxList/>},
          {id:3, content: ""},
          {id:4, content: ""}
        ],
        isModalOpen: false
      }

    }

    handleWidgetSelection=(id) => {

      this.setState({ selectedWidgetId: id }, () => {
        console.log('updated state value', this.state.selectedWidgetId) //this shows up correctly 
       })
    }

    addEvent=(index)=>{
        this.setState({ 
            isModalOpen: true
        })
        const copyWidgets=Object.assign([],this.state.widgets); 
        let widget = Object.assign({}, this.state.widgets[index]);
        console.log(this.state.selectedWidgetId); //this shows up as null 
        widget.content=this.state.widgetOptions.find(w => w.name === this.state.selectedWidgetId).comp;//it is unable to find it in the array because it appears as the original state of null 
        copyWidgets[index]=widget; 
        this.setState({ 
            widgets:copyWidgets

        }) 
    }
   .... 
   render() {
      const { classes } = this.props;

      return (

      <div className={classes.root}>
      <AddWidgetDialog handleWidgetSelection={this.handleWidgetSelection} widgets={this.state.widgetOptions} isModalOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} onRequestClose={this.onRequestClose} />
        <Grid container spacing={24}>
            {
                this.state.widgets.map((widget,index)=>{
                    return(
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                            <Paper className={classes.paper}><Swappable id={widget.id} content={widget.content} delete={this.deleteEvent.bind(this,index)} add={this.addEvent.bind(this,index)}/></Paper>
                         </Grid>
                    )
                })
            }
        </Grid>
      </div>
      );
    }
```

Swappable component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Swappable extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            customFunc: null
        }
    }

    allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    drag(ev, customFunc = null) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("src", ev.target.id);
        console.log(ev.target.parentNode, 'TARGET DRAGSTART')

        this.setState({
            initialParentNode: ev.target.parentNode
        })
    }

    dragEnd(ev, customFunc = null) {

        console.log(ev.target.parentNode, 'TARGET DRAGEND')
        if (customFunc && (ev.target.parentNode != this.state.initialParentNode)) {
            console.log('custom func')
            this.props.customFunc()
        }
    }

    drop(ev, dragableId, dropzoneId, customFunc = null, swappable = true) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        let src = document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("src"));
        let srcParent = src.parentNode;
        let target = document.getElementById(dragableId);

        console.log(src, 'dragged element');
        console.log(srcParent, 'parent of dragged');
        console.log(target, 'element to be swapped')

        swappable ? this.swapElements(src, target, srcParent) : this.transferElement(src, dropzoneId)

    }

    swapElements(src, target, srcParent) {
        target.replaceWith(src);
        srcParent.appendChild(target);
    }

    transferElement(src, dropzoneId) {
        let dropzone = document.getElementById(dropzoneId)
        dropzone.appendChild(src);
    }

    render() {
        const dropZoneStyle = {                          
            width: '450px',
            minHeight: '300px',
            padding: '10px',
            border: '1px solid #aaaaaa'
        };

        const draggableStyle = { 
            width: '400px',
            height: '300px',
            padding: '10px',
            border: '1px solid red'
        };

        const { id, content, swappable, customFunc } = this.props
        const dropzoneId = 'drop' + id
        const dragableId = 'drag' + id

        console.log(customFunc, 'customFunc')
        return (
            <div
                id = {dropzoneId}
                onDrop={(event) => this.drop(event, dragableId, dropzoneId, customFunc, swappable)} 
                onDragOver={(event) => this.allowDrop(event)} 
                style={dropZoneStyle}>
                <div id={ dragableId }
                    draggable="true"
                    onDragStart={(event) => this.drag(event)}
                    onDragEnd = {(event) => this.dragEnd(event, customFunc)}
                    style={draggableStyle}>

                    { content }
                    <div>{content==""?<button onClick={this.props.add}>Add Widget</button>:<button onClick={this.props.delete}>Delete</button>}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Swappable;
```

AddWidgetDialog Component:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

const AddWidgetDialog = ({ handleWidgetSelection, widgets, isModalOpen, onRequestClose}) => {
  const widgetItems = widgets.map((widget) => {
    return (
      <div className="list-group">
      <a href="#" onClick={() => handleWidgetSelection(widget.name)} className="list-group-item">
          <h6 className="list-group-item-heading">{widget.name}</h6>
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return (
    <Modal
      className="Modal__Bootstrap modal-dialog"
      isOpen={isModalOpen}>
      <div className="modal-content">
       <div className="modal-header">
         <button type="button" className="close" onClick={onRequestClose}>
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           <span className="sr-only">Close</span>
         </button>
         <h4 className="modal-title">Add a widget</h4>
       </div>
       <div className="modal-body">
         <h5>Pick a widget to add</h5>
         {widgetItems}
       </div>
       <div className="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={onRequestClose}>Close</button>
       </div>
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default AddWidgetDialog;
```

Comment: When are you exectuting the addEvent function from `Swappable` component

Comment: In the return function for it after the content is displayed, I have added the swappable and the AddWidgetDialog component in my question as an update for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing this
`add={this.addEvent.bind(this,index)}` 
with just arrow function:

```
add={()=> this.addEvent(index)}
```